# Why is the read access to the seed file of CONFIG_GCC_PLUGIN_RANDSTRUCT not restricted to privileged users?

Tags: linux, module, kernel

CONFIG_GCC_PLUGIN_RANDSTRUCT enables a security feature which randomizes data structure layout to raise the attack bar. This feature is implemented as a GCC plugin and the randomization seed file is exposed to users who need to build third-party or out-of-tree kernel modules. Since common users can build kernel modules, an attacker as a common user can read the seed file and thus defeat this randomization.

Why don't we restrict the read access to the seed file to privileged users? Of course, this means we need to compile kernel modules using sudo/root access. But I don't see any reasons to reject it after all installing a kernel module requires sudo/root access.

I build the kernel myself because I fail to find a distros that enables this feature.

Comment: Which risk do you see in someone compiling a kernel module? (As the kernel source code is freely available it is not possible to prevent people from compiling or extending it.)

Comment: A security feature enabled via CONFIG_GCC_PLUGIN_RANDSTRUCT. This feature randomizes data structure layout to raise the attack bar. This feature is implemented as a GCC plugin. To build third-party or out-of-tree kernel modules, the randomization seed is required. Therefore, an attacker can use this to defeat the randomization. If restricting kernel module compilation to privileged users, we need not worry about the seed's exposure because only privileged users can read this.

Comment: So the question is actually: Why is the read access to the seed file (`randomize_layout_seed.h`) not restricted to privileged users? This file should be specific to your system(s) to prevent attacks. Where does this file on your system come from? Did you compile the kernel yourself? Please [edit] your question and add all information there instead of answering in comments.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my question as suggested. :)

Comment: You didn't clarify where the seed file came from. I try to find out who would be responsible for protecting the seed file. Did you build the kernel yourself?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. update.

Comment: If you built the kernel yourself, then you are responsible for the files. Simply restrict the access to the seed file as necessary. If you don't do this, everyone who can read (copy) the file can also build kernel modules on his own computer. It wouldn't make sense to enable this feature in a pre-built kernel because all users would share the same publicly known seed.

Comment: Hmm. I agree. Btw, if I want to evaluate its impact on the performance overhead, which environment and benchmarks shall I use? Because I see that kernel uses two configurations for this feature and one of them is for the performance sensitive scenario. I guess it should have non-negligible performance overhead.

Comment: I wrote my previous comment as an answer. Your latest comment is a totally different question, so you should write a new question. As this is not programming related, you should ask on a different site. I'm not sure, but maybe https://unix.stackexchange.com/ is a suitable place.

Answer (score 0):

If you built the kernel yourself, then you are responsible for the files. Simply restrict the access to the seed file as necessary. If you don't do this, everyone who can read (copy) the file can also build kernel modules on his own computer. It wouldn't make sense to enable this feature in a pre-built kernel because all users would share the same publicly known seed.